# Replicate the look of an HTML style table in MS Word

Tags: html, css, ms-word, ms-office, openoffice-writer

I have this html table that I want to replicate the ***appearance*** of in Word:

[image]

It uses this css (though the Word version doesn't have to be exact):

```
.cell {
              padding: 8px;
              border: 1px #000 solid;
                text-align: center;
            font-size: 1.35em;
          }
  .boxheader {
         color: #000000;
         display: block;
         font-weight: bold;
         text-align: left;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         letter-spacing: 1px;
             font-size: 0.75em;
         }
```

Where each cell is styled:

```
<td class="cell><span class="boxheader">YEAR:</span>0000</td>
```

I need to replicate the "boxheader" in a cell using only MS-Word. I'm not allowed to copy and paste the HTML (I tried and it didn't come out right anyway).

**Is there a way to design a table in Word or Writer that looks like this?**

Comment: This looks off topic in its current form. Are you doing this programmatically, or within Word itself?

Comment: Within word itself. If it is off topic, where do I put it? There isn't a "Stackoverflow for Office" products. I looked before I posted here.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://www.superuser.com).

Comment: I perfectly fine using code to create the document. If someone knows how.

Comment: copy/paste should just work fine . I agree, your off topic here .

Answer (score 1):

I know that you said that you could only use MS Word, but I did not understand if you only had that available or you just could copy the HTML. So here is my idea. I recreated your template in about 5 minutes. If you would like to do it in Word, I suggest that you create it in Excel first. Then copy the contents to Word. The end result is the same and you can modify it in Word after you get it there. Steps to get end result.

- Merge Row 1, Column C and D together.
- Merge Row 2, Column A and B together.
- Merge Row 2, Column D and E together.
- Merge Row 3, Column A through F together.
- Fill in the values
- Add Borders.
- Copy to MS Word

Works like a charm! Hope that helps!

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't think about using Excel!